# Is it possible that someone on my shared host can create a new session to view private data on my website?

Tags: php, security, session, shared-hosting

I know that session hijaking is possible on a shared host, but can someone with a hosting account on the same server as me create his/her own new PHP session and access the member's area on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if he can access the directory where session files are getting stored then YES, he can create a valid session !
You can store session in Database to prevent this !

Comment: It's true that db is best option especially for big data, go for it.. This one session_save_path('./sessions'); might help too some times in a small project.